# shortestpath for an undirected graph using graphshortestpath

Tags: matlab

I tried looking for previous questions about generating shortest path for an undirected graph,but couldn't find any.

The documentation page shows how to change directed graph to undirected graph using tril function.

However, I have generated an undirected graph and want to find the shortest path using the graphshortestpath function.

I am aware of the command 
    '[dist,path,pred] = graphshortestpath(UG,u,v,'directed',false)

Could you tell me how to generate the same for an undirected graph(instead of changing directed to undirected graph using tril command)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting the argument 'Directed' to false in the same function?

[...] = graphshortestpath(..., 'Directed', DirectedValue, ...)

DirectedValue:  Property that indicates whether the graph is directed or undirected. Enter false for an undirected graph. Default is true.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/graphshortestpath.html

Comment: I tried it,but it does not give me the correct shortest path.
for example,


    (4,1) 3
     (1,2) 3
(3,2) 4
(1,3) 8
(4,3) 5
(2,4) 1
(5,4) 6
(1,5) 4
(2,5) 7
for graphshortestpath(UG,1,3,'directed',false)
it gives me distance as 8
and path as 1,4,3
Should it not consider the path 1,2,3 with distance as 7

Comment: :I was able to get the shortest path for undirected graph by first changing the sparse matrix A using 
         'A= tril(A+A')'
         ' [D path pred]=graphshortestpath(A,1,3,'directed',false)'
I was earlier confused about the use of tril function.Got it now.
Thanks.